# mysql how to edit my.ini on some hosting site

Tags: php, mysql, sql, hosting, ini

I had hosted my site on some hosting site. But i want to know that how could i edit my `mysql` full text stop words.

**There is no folder in my home directory** **with name mysql**

As i have hosted my site on some hosting site. So, i don't know how to edit `my.ini` file.

I can edit the file in `localhost`:

```
ft_stopword_file=''
ft_stopword_file='path/to/stopword_file.txt'
```

Please help me how can i edit my `my.ini` on my current online working website file.

Comment: If you need to make specific changes to core installation files. Perhaps a virtual server will provide better functionality for your requirements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on a typical shared-hosting plan, I highly doubt this is possible. Remember that you're sharing a server (and a single MySQL installation) with potentially hundreds of other websites. There are lots of really good reasons why the owner of a shared-hosting server won't want to let their clients edit configuration files

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your hosting site. Some hosting sites make you have a virtual machine where you have your own OS installation and root access. But most (cheaper) hosting plans do not offer this, you will only have a small environment on a big server, shared with alot of other customers.

You will have to check your hosting plan.